# Is there a way to see if a Screen/Route exists in a navigation stack for React Navigation v5?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Depending on if a screen exists in a certain stack I need to be able to do different things in my code. I have tried my best but I haven't found anything on the matter. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean, you want to get all the routes inside the current navigator, then I think this will fix your problem.

```
const navigation = useNavigation();

const routes = navigation.dangerouslyGetState().routeNames;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was idd what I was looking for! Think I just glanced over it

Answer (score 3):

In v.6 :

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
const routes = navigation.getState().routeNames;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my v5.7 it was:

```
const routes = navigation.getRootState().routeNames;
```

Which returns an array of all available routes, so then I was just able to check if it exist by doing this:

```
if (routes.includes('YourRouteNameHere')) {
    console.log('Route exist!');
}
```